# Disabled State on U.S. Map plugin (a JQuery plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dictionary

I want to disable the click/event on some of the states, and make only few states is click-able. 
I read thru the documentation at http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/, and can't find anything related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/#usage-events describes how to bind individual states' events:

```
$('#map').on('usmap<event>MD', function(event, data) {
  console.log('You clicked on the state of Maryland');
});
```

If you're using a general click event handler for the whole map, why not just check for disabled states there?

```
var disabledStates = ["CA", "HI", "AK", "MD"];
$('#map').usmap({
  "click": function(evt, data) {
    for(var each in disabledStates) {
      if(data.name === disabledStates.each) { return false; }
    }
    // do stuff with non-disabled state clicks...
  }
});
```